# Custom made flutter Icon

Tags: flutter, icons

I am developing a flutter application, for which I need to put my own logo as a Bottom Navigation Bar Icon. I have my own .svg file as well as an image file(png, jpeg, etc) of my logo, but I don't know how to use it as Icon in the bottom nav bar(BNB) with other material Icon.
For now, I have 4 icons in BNB and want to place the App Logo icon in center of BNB.
Note: I am building the app for android as well as ios platform.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auxDj.png)

Comment: You'll get the most out of stack overflow if you show what you've tried. Copy your code here, so that others can help you. If you're just looking for a tutorial, there are plenty online (eg https://resocoder.com/2019/08/15/flutter-custom-icons-automatic-manual-way-icon-font-or-svg/).

Comment: please add the error on your question description. Also you need to make sure that the asset image is declared in pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg

Or use https://www.fluttericon.com/ to make your own "native" icons.

Answer (score 0):

using package [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg), put the widget inside yout `items` list in `BottomNavigationBar`

```
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/logo.svg',
          height: 40.0,
          width: 40.0,
          color: Colors.black,),
    title: Text('Some Title'))
```

Comment: I tried this approach and the code is throwing errors.
1. the value of const list literal must be constant
2. The constructor being called isn't a const constructor

Comment: remove the const keyword. can you just show the code in your description.?

Answer (score 0):

#### SVG to Icon font family

You can use [icon_font_generator](https://pub.dev/packages/icon_font_generator) to convert from SVG icon to icon font family.

- Firstly, make sure to copy SVG icon to your project and follow the structure which can be found package doc.
- To generate icon code, run these commands (it required node js):

```sh
$ flutter pub global activate icon_font_generator
$ export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/Tools/flutter/.pub-cache/bin"
$ icon_font_generator --from=icons --class-name=Iconly --out-font=lib/src/icon_font/iconly.ttf --out-flutter=lib/src/widgets/icons.dart
```

This will generate following files:

```
lib/src/icon_font/iconly.ttf
lib/src/widgets/icons.dart
```

Final `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  icon_font_generator: ^1.0.0

flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Iconly
      fonts:
        - asset: lib/src/icon_font/iconly.ttf
```

Usage:

```dart
var icon = const Icon(Iconly.outline2User);
```

[image]

NOTE:  there might be wrong rendering for complex SVG file.